# How can I add my business logic to the authentication of spring cloud oauth?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

In the oauth server side(auth microservice),I try to implement the oauth center by spring security and jwt, here is the Code of my UserDetailService:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws 
UsernameNotFoundException {
    ManagerInfo managerInfo = userMapper.getUserByLoginName(username);
    if(managerInfo ==null)
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("sorry,can not find user of "+username+"！");
    Collection<Role> roleList =roleMapper.getRoleByUserId(managerInfo.getId());
    String roleIds = roleList.stream().map(role ->role.getId().toString()).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    Collection<Authority> authorities =authorityMapper.getAuthoritiesByRoleIds(roleIds);
    CustomUserPrincipal userDetail = new CustomUserPrincipal(managerInfo.getUsername(),managerInfo.getPassword(),
authorities);
    userDetail.setUser(managerInfo);
    return userDetail;
}
```

The CustomUserprincipal just extends org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User,and the Authority implements org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority.

In my gateway project , I try to use spring boot(version:1.5.9.RELEASE) and here is some dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Now,I have successfully authenticate the user by "prePostEnabled" way,here is the controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getUserById/{id}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('LIST_USER')")
CollectionAccount getUserById(@PathVariable String id){
   return managerService.getCollectionAccount(Long.parseLong(id));
}
```

All the code I have written works great,and the user have 'LIST USER' authority which is returned by the userdetailservice can access this method.

But,what if I want to authenticate the user by resource type,not just the authority string?

Or add some business logic to the authentication, like 'A_PARK_LIST_USER','B_PARK_LIST_USER' and so on,maybe the user login in just have 'A_PARK_LIST_USER' and can not list the user of "B_PARK",so I can not control the access right just by'LIST USER', how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to inject the AuthenticationPrincipal into the controller method.

Try this:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getUserById/{id}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('LIST_USER')")
    CollectionAccount getUserById(@PathVariable String id, @AuthenticationPrincipal Principal principal){
        //Here you have the users information, the principal.getName() will be the username that has been authenticated
        log.debug(principal.getName());
        return managerService.getCollectionAccount(Long.parseLong(id));
    }
```